# C : how to handle all the exit code status for bash commands

Tags: c, bash

I'm working on a simulate of bash in C.

I faced this problem while I'm trying to handle the exit status code of some command.

for example:

```
bash-3.2$ ./asid
bash: ./asid: No such file or directory
bash-3.2$ echo $?
127
bash-3.2$ .
bash: .: filename argument required
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
bash-3.2$ echo $?
2
bash-3.2$
```

in the example above when the command execute bash set a exit status in $?, I'm trying to simulate the same behavior to my code.

my code so far:

```
int     ft_exec(t_simple_cmd *cmd, t_env **head)
{
    int     pid;
    int     status;
    int     f_status;


    if (!(pid = fork()))
    {
        //child_process;
        if (execve(cmd->command, ft_args_to_arr(cmd), ft_list_to_arr(head)) == -1)
            ft_put_err(cmd->command, ft_strjoin(": ", strerror(errno)), 2);
        exit(errno);
    }
    else if (pid == -1)
    {
        //error;
        ft_putstr_fd("Fork failed.\n", 2);
    }
    else
    {
        //parent process;
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        f_status = WEXITSTATUS(status);
        return (f_status);
    }
    return (1);
}
```

when I'm trying the same commands in my bash I git different result.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], this would include *complete* runnable code, the input, the desired output, and the actual output.

Comment: To be clear, is your `ft_exec` call supposed to return the value that's put into your shell's equivalent of `$?` ?

Comment: @pilcrow yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you will ultimately put the `int` return of your `ft_exec(_cmd_, _env_)` into your shell's equivalent of the `$?` variable from `sh`.

The [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_02) for `$?` imposes a number of constraints:  eight bits of information, normal process termination represented as a number 0–125, errors of shell expansion or redirection between 1–125, non-executable files failing invocation as 126, missing commands as 127, and signal death as greater than 128.

With that in mind, this logic:

```
if (execve(...) == -1) {
  exit(errno);  // This is incorrect!
}
```

cannot be correct.  You need to translate [`execve`'s errors](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html#tag_16_111_05) into a `$?` of 126 or 127 yourself.

Comment: thank you for yor help.
but I have problem: for example in `sh` when the error `bash: ./sopajpd: No such file or directory` the exit status is `127` but when I tried your answer the exit code is `2`.

Comment: No, my answer is to return 127 yourself. Do _not_ pass errno along.